# Looping through UICollectionViewLayouts doesn't work, but stepping through does. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The code for this issue is on GitHub: [Circles](https://github.com/jcedman/circles)

I am trying to "animate" an expansion of a UICollectionView with custom layouts.

The starting position is:

[image]

The ending position is:

[image]

The problem is that the expansion doesn't proceed stepwise when looping through an array of custom layouts using various different strategies like:

```
for layout in self.layoutArray { //where layoutArray is an array of UICollectionViewLayout(s)

        // DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.circleCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.circleCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)

        self.circleCollectionView.reloadData()

         // }

        }
```

Basically, the above "waits" to display the intermediate steps and then does them all at once (I think - may just be doing the last one) before display.

I can "step through the layouts" and each "intermediate" loads and displays as expected using:

```
 @IBAction func stepAction(_ sender: Any) {

 z = z + 1   //stepping through layoutArray


 // DispatchQueue.main.async {
 self.circleCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
 self.circleCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.layoutArray[self.z], animated: true)
 //self.circleCollectionView.reloadData()

 //}


}
```

Stepping through:

[image]

I have looked through gitHub thoroughly and elsewhere and can't find an answer.

BTW,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
```

and several other ways of "forcing" the processes to complete, don't appear to solve the issue.

Comment: i think using self.circleCollectionView.reloadData() after setting collectionviewlayout will force layout to be set without animation and you see it suddenly. you should performBatchUpdates to animate your new layouts

Comment: Do you mean to get rid of reloadData()? That doesn't work. Nor does the following:  ` self.circleCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
                
                self.circleCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.circleCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
                
                //self.circleCollectionView.reloadData()
                
            }, completion:nil) `